# Microphone keeps turning on and off

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, microphone

Hello brothers and sisters,

I am a clean keyboard freak, and one day I chose to spray a detergent directly on the keyboard rather than the cloth. The result, you ask? Horrible and strange, to say the least. The funny thing is, it has phases, so I guess I have to describe it all. At times, I can use all the buttons, but then something happens, and I can't use the plus sign, or the numbers 5 and six(5 works on the numerical at least). Certain buttons also turn the microphone on and off, like the division sign, h and g, among others. Now I can't use CTRL plus C as well, because it does not work in the era that denies me some buttons, but I suppose it will magically switch soon. In both eras or modes, the microphone turns itself off and on with some keys. All of this I can live with, as I can simply just use an external keyboard, but I simply cannot live with the microphone turning itself on and off by itself. I tried turning off the keyboard shortcut for the mic in the settings, but it did not help.

I know that this problem is as stupid as it gets, but I must ask you for suggestions nonetheless. Is there a way I can make this stop? I have a Lenovo IdeaPad L340 Gaming(just turned my mic on and off by writing Gaming). I will be thankful for any suggestions at all.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brpKQ.png)

Comment: You killed the keyboard it is full of sticky stuff from the soap. Replace the keyboard. BTW This is in no way related to Ubuntu.

Comment: I was just wondering if there was a way to stop it somehow, like to completely turn off the internal microphone or something. To disallow its function, thus eradicate this unpleasant condition. It is not related to Ubuntu, but I have faith in the Linux minds, as I used to find them more sophisticated in the past when I consulted them. Furthermore, I do not use Windows, so I do not know if the same thing would have occurred, but this may be due to my lack of understanding of the computer universe.

Comment: And it was an all-surfaces solution. It just couldn't handle the shine.